# When using a Windows Key shortcut, Start Menu always opens, even though a shortcut was used for something else, why?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

Whenever I use a [Windows key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key) shortcut, for example <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for run, <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for aero peek (for desktop), the Windows [start menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_menu) will open.

In [Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8), this did not happen to me. I could use the Windows key as a shortcut and it would only register the shortcut I was using. However, in [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1), if I use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>some key</kbd>, no matter what the shortcut is for, *after* the Windows key is released, the start menu will open. This means that to take a screenshot with the Windows shortcut, I would be pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> ... <kbd>Win</kbd>. It would take the screenshot, and then when I let go of the keys, it would open the start menu. And then I would press <kbd>win</kbd> again to close it. Why does this happen? It's very frustrating...

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem in Windows 10, though for me the start menu opens as soon as I press the windows key.

Comment: @zeel – Any 3rd-party start menu utilities installed? Or keyboard helper? Or bloatware coming with new PC? Could you prepare your computer for restart and then kill any unessential processes one by one? After each kill, test key shortcut again. People sometimes have [similar problems with other keys](http://superuser.com/q/881330/287473). Poorly written tools and utilities can cause this.

Comment: No, nothing like that. I have a computer that this happens, on... and one where it does not. And they are virtually identical as far as software.