# How to stop Alt+Shift+1 closing the current app?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text

Whenever I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, it seems to close the currently focused application window.

I don't want this behavior, especially since they are used for application-level hotkeys (Sublime Text 2/3).

Any way to remove/change this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out, a new version of [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/?lang=en) has added some new keybindings that doesn't close the window but moves them to another "virtual desktop."

Solved by disabling those keybindings in Dexpot.

Answer (score 12):

Such weird keyboard shortcuts usually do not come from Windows, but from some more or less legitimate software (often bloatware) which comes installed with it by manufacturer. Or they may even originate in software added by you. Sometimes they come with upgrade of sotware which was harmless before. To find out the evil-doer, start killing your background apps until this goes to normal.

Please see [answer to similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649734/cannot-catch-ctrlaltf1-in-winforms-mdi-is-it-special).