# Windows wont let me type Shift+F

Tags: keyboard

I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet, for some reason windows wont let me type Shift+F. I tried turning on caps lock and pressing Shift+F, still nothing. I know this is not hardware because I tried it with multiple keyboards. I closed everything that my computer let me close, but nothing. It's probably a windows option. Does anyone know what this could be? (I think its something to do with the Control panel) running windows 7

Comment: There not going to be a "user can't use Shift+F" option. ;)  Have you performed a reboot yet?  Does regular "F" work?  Does "Shift" work with other keys?  If you log into Windows in Safe Mode, does it work as expected there?

Comment: Safe mode is too long and sluggish of a process. I just tried launching it many times but never worked. I tried rebooting as I did the safe mode thing, still doesnt work. f does work regularly, thats how I can use caps lock + f. And shift works with other keys.

Comment: "Safe mode is too long and sluggish of a process"  What does that mean?  "I just tried launching it many times but never worked" If you can't boot in safe mode, then you have a bigger problem than your Shift+F not working.

Comment: You need to give the community longer than an hour before you start to asking that question.  I would provide us more information if you want an answer though

Comment: @TheGuythatisTheOne – I advice you to stop bumping here, this is not a fast-reply board. Also please (1) check my updated answer below and (2) [edit] your question to provide others details they are asking. Low quality questions attract downvotes and close votes, it can happen that your question gets closed so I'd advice you to cooperate.

Comment: @TheGuythatisTheOne I have flagged your inappropriate behavior to a moderator.  I strongly suggest improving the quality of your question instead of "bumping" your question with a comment because it doesn't actually bump your question...to the first page.

Comment: You think I would mark your's as answer after you reporting me AND downvoting? OF COURSE not.

Comment: @TheGuythatisTheOne – (1) please where you found I reported or downvoted the question? (2) Some people asked you for input, you did not answer them, but perhaps you ignored them. So some of them reported and downvoted question of low quality, don't you think they were right? (3) You do not need to mark my answer, just mark the most helpful answer.

Comment: Well I didnt mark anything (Even if helpful) for answer. Yours didnt help AT ALL

Comment: Hi there, sorry to reply so late but I had the same issue as you, turns out it was a silly issue with my keyboard, a gaming one which is not integrated into my laptop. 
You see, on my keyboard there are buttons one can use to access things quickly, for example there is a button with a magnifying glass which when clicked shows windows search. It turns out that that button was stuck and as a result shift+f did not work for me. When i used my laptop keyboard it worked fine, just this one. So i unstuck the button and voila shift+f works again!

Answer (score 2):

This question is repeating for various hotkeys here on the SuperUser. One of the easiest ways to rule out the problem is to prepare your computer for restart and then **start killing applications and processes**, starting with most likely ones. **After each kill, check whether the shortcut is still taken.** This way you will determine which application/process caused the problem.

Please see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28650058/2392157) and [case similar to yours](https://superuser.com/a/881333/287473).

EDIT:
You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to get real overview of all processes. It will perhaps show more than you were able to see. Then you also can start stopping the services.

**A. stop non-Microsoft processes**

1. Run Processs Explorer.
2. menu **View** > **Show processes from all users** ← check this item if it is not checked.
3. menu **View** > **Select columns...**: on **Process Image** tab check **Company Name**.

   Now concentrate on all the software which is **not from the Microsoft.** Most likely the software from the Microsoft is not causing the problem. Observe column *Company Name* in the table, so you can quickly recognize non-Microsoft processes and kill them all.

**B. stop non-Microsoft services**

1. Open Windows **Services** console
2. Stop every service which has path different than **C:\Windows** – you can see the path when you open properties of each service.

Remeber to test the keyboard shortcut after each termination.

Comment: Did nothing. I closed everything didnt work.

Comment: @TheGuythatisTheOne – please see the updated answer.

Comment: I closed everything in explorer on Process explorer, including what was under it (Everything I was allowed to delete by it) and nothing happened.

Comment: @TheGuythatisTheOne – please see the updated answer on how to properly run Process Explorer. Also focus on stopping non-Microsoft services as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Global hotkeys can be registered by any application on Windows. So most probably an application has taken this shortcut.

On Windows 7 it seems to be safe to use [Windows Hotkey Explorer](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) to see which one it is.

Source: [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

Comment: I found shift+f in the hotkey explorer, how do I fix that?

Comment: Also shift+f says its just empty no programs apparently

Comment: this was closest I guess... But I have to BUY commander later on. I Could disable the Shift+F shortcut, using windows hotkey commander.  But I cant set anything as answer because I have negative votes. With negeative votes I refuse to mark as answer