# High ping (up to 300 ms) on WI-FI (Only in one computer)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router, connection, ping

I have two computers on the same Network, one is an HP 15 Notebook PC and the other one is an Asus X541UV. They are both running Windows 10 and connected using WI-FI technology.

I've noticed that Asus has a very slow WI-FI connection so I tested ping to 192.168.1.1 (the router) on both of them, this is the results

On HP Notebook 15 (Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter):

```
C:\Users\HP>ping 192.168.1.1

Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  192.168.1.1 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=8 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=2 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=3 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=1 ms TTL=64

Statistiques Ping pour 192.168.1.1:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 8ms, Moyenne = 3ms
```

On Asus X541UV (Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC):

```
C:\Users\ASUS>ping 192.168.1.1

Envoi d’une requête 'Ping'  192.168.1.1 avec 32 octets de données :
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=14 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=299 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=109 ms TTL=64
Réponse de 192.168.1.1 : octets=32 temps=127 ms TTL=64

Statistiques Ping pour 192.168.1.1:
    Paquets : envoyés = 4, reçus = 4, perdus = 0 (perte 0%),
Durée approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
    Minimum = 14ms, Maximum = 299ms, Moyenne = 137ms
```

> Notice : *ping* looks normal using Ethernet cable on ASUS
>
> P.S : Both wirless drivers are up to date

Comment: A ping over such a small amount of time is a terrible way to test. You need to run a longer ping - try using `ping -n 1000` to send 1000 pings, or `ping -t` to ping forever (until stopped using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c<kbd>. You also say one has a very slow wifi connection - Provide all the details from `ipconfig /a` in your question for both laptops, and consider checking for interference such as microwaves, or cordless phones.

Comment: hello @djsmiley2k i have slow wifi only on ASUS , HP and other devices are working fine so there is no interference.

On Asus websites takes too much to load (videos and all media also) i've changed the DNS and nothing happens , Now i'm using ethernet cable on ASUS (and it's working fine with ethernet) to download a windows 10 update and everything is okay 
about ipconfig /all it shows the network adapter that i mentioned above and ip adresses + gateway (they are useless i guess)

Comment: Can you list down the processes which are running in both the PC's during test ?...most of the times there are these "network optimizer" or some third party applications which might cause this issue. You can even try running the ping tests in Windows safe mode and check if you are getting same ping on the PC, if its same ..then the processes running in the system are not guilty , else ...its on one of the process.

Comment: Hello @NWishAll , I've already checked for network usage of processess and it's normal there is no process using a lot of download from the network. the HP has alot of softwares installed and running and it's working fine while the ASUS (the one with WI-FI problem) is almost empty, i just bought it and it has slow connection only using WI-FI

Comment: Just in case, can you run the ping test with safe mode ON?( I am not denying the point that you put about the processes not being the culprit, but I need to know the system behaviour in safe mode for the same)

Comment: Try increasing power to the wireless network adapter in the ASUS computer. Check the power plan options (accessible through the battery icon), go into the details and set the wireless adapter to maximum performance. Also note that when plugged in the performance can increase.

Comment: hello guys, thanks for your efforts and time
i guess the problem comes from windows , i've tried the linux live cd on ASUS and WIFI is just fine, i'm not sure what is the problem with windows
@TomerGodinger the performance stays the same either plugged to the sector ot not and all wireless settings are fine, maybe it's because of the driver or because of the windows O.S i'm not realy sure
anyway thanks all for your efforts and time (sorry for responding late)

Comment: The driver might indeed be at fault. Try updating it.

Comment: @TomerGodinger it's up to date (last version) :(

Comment: I actually just remembered something similar - try updating your router firmware and setting `802.1Q` with a `VLANID=0` and `802.1P=0` in its settings. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1255205/756089) to a similar problem, which is based on the solution suggested [here](https://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?SLanguage=en-us&id=20160101061223931&board_id=11&model=DSL-AC68U).

Comment: okay @TomerGodinger I will try it .
Thanks a lot for your time and efforts (y) (y)